# Delete a row if the absolute value of all columns are less than 1?

Tags: filter, row, multiple-columns

I need to delete rows a table (.csv) only if in all column absolute values for that row are less than 1, how can I accomplish this?

Example

```
Year Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3 Parameter4
1       -0.3       0.1       -2.5        1.0
2       -0.3       0.1        0.8        0.1
3       -0.3       0.1       -3.8        1.6
4       -0.6       0.5       -0.2        0.4
5        0.3      -0.1       -0.5        1.3
```

And I want to output to result in:

```
Year Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3 Parameter4
1       -0.3       0.1       -2.5        1.0
3       -0.3       0.1       -3.8        1.6
5        0.3      -0.1       -0.5        1.3
```

Thanks in advance!